# AJAXed Select form element defaults to first option even if changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

**Updated**: The DOM is creating a second select instance of `#dockhouse-reservation-vessel`. It's overriding the first which is the "real" one with the right value

The events are triggered, data retrieved and replaced. `#dockhouse-reservation-vessel`'s value shows in an `alert()` but not in `$_POST`. If I comment out the second block of jQuery, the problematic `select`'s value is remembered correctly.

```
$('form').delegate('#dockhouse-reservation-owner','change', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dockhouse/ajax/vessels/' + $(this).val() +  '/',
        success: function(data){
            $('#dockhouse-reservation-vessel').empty();
            $('#dockhouse-reservation-vessel').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

`data` represents `option` elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<option value="">Choose a vessel</option>
<option value="1744">Stinkpot</option>
<option value="1726">Poopy Snoop</option>
<option value="1704">Catchup</option>
```

The `data` below represents a table.

```
$('form').delegate('#dockhouse-reservation-vessel','change',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dockhouse/ajax/locations-by-reservation-criteria/' + $(this).val() +  '/',
        success: function(data){
            $('#assign-location').empty();
            $('#assign-location').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does `data` look like coming from the server? Are you replacing the select with another select?

Comment: @czarchaic, I've updated my question with new jQuery too. Same problem. I'm now appending `option` elements to the `select`.

Comment: @czarchaic, looking at the DOM it is creating a second select instance. It's overriding the first which is the "real" one with the right value.

Comment: The second block of jQuery code appears to create a new instance of the field based on the original DOM...? I don't understand what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are removing and reinserting the whole select box, the state is removed.
You can save the old value in a temp variable and apply it in the callback:

```
$('form').delegate('#dockhouse-reservation-vessel','change',function(){
        // save the value
        var oldValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/dockhouse/ajax/locations-by-reservation-criteria/' + oldValue +  '/',
            success: function(data){
                $('#assign-location').empty();
                $('#assign-location').append(data);
                // select the old value
                $('#dockhouse-reservation-vessel').val(oldValue);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW, stupid mistake. There was a select field with the same name being pulled in with the table ajax response. Walks away in shame...